# Iterating through list of values as part of formula in Raster Calculator of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, iterator

I am trying to create animation of one density raster layer gradually changing to another density raster layer. My idea is to create multiple intermediate raster layers and put them in one group layer in arcscene for animation purpose.

Right now,  for the sake of argument let's call these two raster layers A and B. My way of doing this is: use Raster Calculator to acquire the difference, let's call it D or Delta. Therefore, I can use Raster Calculator to get my intermediate layers with the formulas of:

- A + 0.2B
- A + 0.4B
- A + 0.6B
  And so on

However, if I want more layers I will make the increments smaller and it will be imprudent to manually put in all these values. My current model is shown as below[image: Current Model]

Therefore I am wondering if there is any way to use iterator or arcpy (some format like [0.1, 1, 0.1]) to insert a list of value as part of the formula in raster calculator: A + "input"*B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the For iterator which could create your incremental steps and feed into your equation using inline substitution. So search help to find out about the **For** iterator and **inline substitution**.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I put the string values like 0.1, 0.2 etc in the model as a input variable.

Comment: inline substitution

Comment: Haha, cool. Checking it out now